# A bounded sequence has a convergent subsequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Let ${a_n}$ be a bounded sequence of real numbers. Prove that ${a_n}$ has a subsequence that converges to lim sup $a_n$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\limsup a_n$ is, by definition, the largest limit point of the sequence $a_n$. When you work with Real numbers (or, more generally, when you work with 1st-countable spaces), for every limit point, $a$ , there is a sequence of points that converge to $a$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** What is the definition of $\limsup$? Try to use the definition and a sequence involving something like $1/n$ to construct such a subsequence.